# The filter must display a default Group

Tags: javascript, html

I have here a HTML select form, that displays groups and categories. When I open the page it shows all the content from each category, what I want to do, is when opening the page to display the content only from Group 1 for example.

Here is the HTML:

```
        <span class="select_label">View Content: </span>
        <select id="content_select">
            <option value="ALL">Choose category</option>
            <optgroup label="Group 1">
                <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 2">
                <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
                <option value="cat2" class="optionGroup">cat2</option>
                <option value="cat3" class="optionGroup">cat3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 3">
                <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
                <option value="cat2" class="optionGroup">cat2</option>
                <option value="cat3" class="optionGroup">cat3</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="Group 4">
                <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
                <option value="cat2" class="optionGroup">cat2</option>
                <option value="cat3" class="optionGroup">cat3</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
```

And I have this script that manages the filtering:

```
<script>
    // FILTER

    $('#content_select').change(function(){

        var criteria = $(this).val();



        if(criteria == 'ALL'){
            $('.content_block').show();
            return;
        }
        $('.filter_category').each(function(i,option){

            if($(this).html() == criteria){
                $(this).parent().show();
            }else {
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Please help, how I can display the content from one group only, let's say a default group.

Comment: Where is the remaining markup? You're missing `.content_block` and `.filter_category`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not very clear what you're trying to do without all the markup.

I wrote this script that hides all the other **<optgroups>** when you select a value.
Maybe you can use that to create what you wanted

```
$('#content_select').change(function(){
  // find the selected option, then its optgroup parent, then all the others optgroups
  var optgroups = $(this).find('option:selected').parent().siblings()

  // add their children, and hide them
  optgroups.add(optgroups.children()).hide()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add `id`s to your `optgroup`s and hide all except one

HTML:

```
<optgroup id="g1" label="Group 1">
    <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup id="g2" label="Group 2">
    <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
    <option value="cat2" class="optionGroup">cat2</option>
    <option value="cat3" class="optionGroup">cat3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup id="g3" label="Group 3">
    <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
    <option value="cat2" class="optionGroup">cat2</option>
    <option value="cat3" class="optionGroup">cat3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup id="g4" label="Group 4">
    <option value="cat1" class="optionGroup">cat1</option>
    <option value="cat2" class="optionGroup">cat2</option>
    <option value="cat3" class="optionGroup">cat3</option>
</optgroup>
```

CSS:

```
#content_select optgroup {
    display: none;
}

#content_select #g2 {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bc65u/)

and the same without CSS but jQuery instead

```
$('#content_select optgroup').hide();
$('#content_select #g2').show();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bc65u/1/)